# Maintaining Zener voltage @ 0.9 of Zener voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator, zener

I have a strange question (at least to me.)

Suppose I have a Zener diode, to be very specific, [1N5234B](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/1N5234B-192181.pdf).

It has a Vz = 6.2V, Izk = 0.25mA, Iz max = 80.645mA.

Suppose I have want that Zener to maintain 90% of its Vz, AKA Vout = 0.9 * Vz = 5.58V in the following circuit, and I want to calculate the load resistance that will satisfy this equation if possible.

Is that even possible?

[image]

I tried using Izk in my calcuations, and things turned out fine on Multisim, but I do not believe that is true, is not Izk supposed to be the minimum current value that will hold Vz at 6.2V?

Here is another picture of the Multisim results, and Iz is *less than* Izk.

What did I miss here?

[image]

Comment: *I have want that zener to maintain 90% of its Vz* Then the zener will not "Zener", meaning you would not benefit from the zener effect (breakdown). Your circuit becomes a **voltage divider** and the Zener diode **isn't doing anything** so you can just remove it! Note how the current though the Zener diode is a) very large b) nominal value c) extremely small? So congratulations, you made a **resistive voltage divider**.

Comment: Essentially R1/R2 are providing a potential divider that applies 5.589V to the zener, which draws close to zero current, as one would expect.  Iz is less than Izk because Vz is less than Vzk.  What’s the purpose of this circuit?

Comment: Zener diodes have very non-linear characteristics especially near their Vz point.  You will find that it's virtually impossible to maintain a voltage since this is not what Zeners are designed to do.  If you want to maintain a 5.58V signal use a different zener with that Vz or use a voltage regulator circuit instead.

Comment: Thank you all, now I understand.

Comment: Just get a 5.6 volt zener diode instead.

Comment: Use a voltage regulator like LM317.   You set the voltage using a pair of fixed resistors.  You can easily set whatever voltage you want with high accuracy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is simple, in this case you can calculate Rload so that it forms a voltage divider circuit with Rs, the Zener won't have any effect because you can model it as an open switch when a voltage *below* the Zener voltage is applied to the Zener in the reverse bias.
Hence the Zener draws nearly zero current in the simulation results.

So the obtained Vout (which is equal to 0.9 * Vz) is actually from the voltage divider *not* the Zener charactersitics or Zener effect.